# Windows: can I redirect all requests coming from my machine for a web URL to a local resource instead?

Tags: windows, redirect, hosts

Let's say that I want, for customisation purposes, replace (only for me) specific CSS / Javascript / pictures / whatever on a give website.
So when the browsers asks to download an asset from a known list of web-based URLs, it is redirected to another one of my choice coming from my computer.

Is there a way to do this?